# Future proof Tweeting with PHP

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm looking to implement a system for tweeting directly from my site backend, which is written in PHP 5. I have a script from the internet that I can adapt, but I'm concerned that when Twitter switches to Oauth only, I'll be out in the cold.

Basically, I'm hoping someone can point me toward a script/tutorial that will let me do the following:

- access twitter via the Oauth system
- Post Tweets and receive error codes
- Let me define an application/site name (I'm a bit fuzzy on whether Twitter allows this)

Ideally I need all 3 points explained in detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the twitteroauth library: http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth - "The first PHP Library to support OAuth for Twitter's REST API". Works great.

You can register a Twitter application here: http:// dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Once you register a Twitter app you'll get an app-specific consumer key/token and secret, which you can then use with the twitteroauth library to access the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start with right at the source. http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Getting-Started